# How can I compute the sigma points for UKF?

Tags: covariance, gaussian, kalman-filter

[image: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-unscented-kalman-filter-anything-ekf-can-do-i-can-do-it-better-ce7c773cf88d]

Image above & tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-unscented-kalman-filter-anything-ekf-can-do-i-can-do-it-better-ce7c773cf88d

I am confused about how to compute the sigma points for the unscented Kalman filter. For me, mu is a 2-dim vector, so n is 5 and cov is a 2x2 matrix. lambda is 3-n, so 1. Now, I don't understand the index i, since non of the values/matrices are dependent on i. What would be the difference between `X[1]` and `X[2]`?

Thanks for any help, I think I'm probably just confused.. :)

Comment: Ah, is it just the i'th column?

Comment: Yes, it's the i'th column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized `i` simply stands for the i'th columnn.